# SPFx webpart issue in Custom Master Page

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I'm getting below error when I add the SPFx app Webpart in Sharepoint Online page with custom master page.

Uncaught Error: Multiple anonymous defines in module https://component-id.invalid/597e7384-2f7a-47bc-95c5-5cb62d43b058_0.0.1/hfHomePageStrings
    at l.eval [as reduceRegister_] (eval at  (sp-classic-page-assembly_en-us_b80981cd18dbc8ee3c3917c9b8f6494e.js:471), :5:14395)
    at HTMLScriptElement.m (eval at  (sp-classic-page-assembly_en-us_b80981cd18dbc8ee3c3917c9b8f6494e.js:471), :5:72)

Comment: Resolved the issue by reordering the custom scripts added in the master page. Previously the custom scripts were added in Body tag and I moved it to head tag the issue resolved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got a same error like this  Multiple anonymous defines in module https://component-id.invalid/e93f02cd-6604-48d2-a9ac-ca2bb6975b90_0.0.1/jquery

Comment: Same issue, your workaround worked for me. Strange issue though